# Cannot send request from Postman via my IP

Tags: http, postman, http-get

Strange thing - I have host API on localhost it works proper (via browser). It's a part of bigger project.
I use Postman for testing endpoints, and when I make request via localhost or 127:

-`https://localhost:7257/esp32`

-`https://127.0.0.1:7257/esp32`

Postman gives me Status 200 OK and fine data from API, but if I send request via my IP adress:

-`https://192.168.8.xxx:7257/esp32` then I see error like this: `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.8.xxx:7257`

What does it cause? Is it correct or no?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I need to host my application on the outside.